# How can I convert encoding of special characters in python?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have have a file includes some sentences. But some of them contains some wired characters (√•, √§, √Ñ), shown below. What are they and is there a way convert them back to normal characters in python?

Thanks,

Examples.

`Is there an outdoor grill/bbq place? P√§r`

`Hej Hur l√•ngt aa√§r de till Stallarna? MVH LAILA`

`√Ñr d√§r sandstrand och hur l√•ngt`

Comment: if you know what char should be in place of `√•` then use `text = text.replac("√•", expected_char)`. But maybe this text uses different encoding then you used to decode it - ie. `Latin1`, `Latin2`, `cp1250`, `iso-8859-2`, etc. Maybe if you use different encoding then you get correct chars.

Comment: or maybe your system use different UTF-8 encoding. As I know MacOS use little different encoding and it can make problems. BTW: I found this on Stackoverflow: [How to decode these characters? √° √© √≠](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283189/how-to-decode-these-characters-%E2%88%9A-%E2%88%9A-%E2%88%9A%E2%89%A0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it used wrong encoding - `MacRoman` - instead of `UTF-8`. Probably it is MacOS system.

If I encode it (to bytes) using `MacRoman` and then decode it back to string using `utf-8` then I get correct text

```
text = '''Is there an outdoor grill/bbq place? P√§r

Hej Hur l√•ngt aa√§r de till Stallarna? MVH LAILA

√Ñr d√§r sandstrand och hur l√•ngt'''

text = text.encode('MacRoman').decode('utf-8') 
print(text)
```

Result:

```
Is there an outdoor grill/bbq place? Pär

Hej Hur långt aaär de till Stallarna? MVH LAILA

Är där sandstrand och hur långt
```

---

Tested on Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7

Information about `MacRoman` from question [How to decode these characters? √° √© √≠](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283189/how-to-decode-these-characters-%E2%88%9A-%E2%88%9A-%E2%88%9A%E2%89%A0)